# Check if input is equal to a value present in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, cin

I want to check if the `input` is equal to any of the options in an array. 
How do I do it? Can I do it without using a lot of `||` operators?

```
    //check if any input in herp[] was entered
    string input;
    string herp[2] = {"Merp", "Derp"}
    cin >> input;
    if (input == "connect "+herp[0]||"connect "+herp[1]) {
        cout << "poopie" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: If you do use `||`, remember that you need the whole comparision in each branch: `input == "this" || input == "that"`, not `input == "this" || "that"`.

Answer (score 12):

Use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
#include <algorithm>

if (std::find(std::begin(herp), std::end(herp), input) != std::end(herp)) {
    cout << "found it!";
}
```

Also, in C++11, [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) has been added. You'll need a predicate function, here in a form of a lambda:

```
if (std::any_of(std::begin(herp), std::end(herp),
    [&input](const std::string& str) { return str == input; })) {
    cout << "found it!";
}
```

I'd also suggest that you don't use raw arrays, but `std::vector` or `std::array` instead. It might not matter if it's in the same function, but when you pass C-arrays around, they decay to pointers and then things quickly get messy.

Comment: You forgot the prefix ("connect ").

Comment: You could use `std::any_of` also.

Comment: @NikosC. Indeed I did. I leave it as an exercise, then :)

Comment: @Nawaz Thanks, added that. It's a shame that there's no overload that takes a value.

Answer (score 3):

Consider replacing your data structure for `herp`; use `std::set` if you need the strings to be ordered or `std::unordered_set` otherwise. Then it's a simple check to see if `herp.find(input) != herp.end()`. These data structures will provide you better complexity guarantees for the find operation (logarithmic and constant amortized for `std::set` and `std::unordered_set` respectively) over using `std::find` on an array (linear). However, these details are less important if you don't expect the size of `herp` to ever grow beyond 2.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to append anything:

```
std::string* p = std::find(std::begin(herp), std::end(herp), input);
if (p != std::end(herp))
{
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
}
```

If you do need to append something, there are a lot of different options.  One of them:

```
std::vector<std::string> herps;

std::string myAppend(const std::string& a)
{
    return "connect " + a;
}

std::transform(std::begin(herp), std::end(herp), std::back_inserter(herps), myAppend);
std::string* p = std::find(herps.begin(), herps.end(), input);
if (p != herps.end())
{
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Rather than constantly creating new strings for each one that you have to compare it would be more efficient to copy his input once and **remove** the leading component or fail if not found. then you only have to do that mess once. reducing to a simpler subproblem

Comment: @UpAndAdam:  I assume you are referring to the second option, since the first option doesn't assume the concatenation is needed.  I agree that it isn't the most efficient method, but it is one where the process is clear to see.  Personally, I like jrok's lambda solution better, but when someone is just learning, the lambda syntax may not be clear.

Comment: Yes I was referring to the second, but my point was that as a first step before EITHER of your solutions you could apply this modification and then the problem IS reduced to your or jroc's solution alone. No lambda syntax needed, just transform the input before the find and comparison.. basically just changes 'input' as passed to find instead of transforming the whole array. Think about the cost if there are a million elements... O(N) + search time.. vs O(1) + search time

Comment: The same could be said for simply appending the `"connect "` to the hard-coded strings you are searching (when they are declared).  In practice, I tend not to modify a search string prior to (or during) the search to avoid situations similar to what you get with Google (Search for "XXXX" and have it return "Showing results for YYYY, did you really mean YYYY?  Click here to show results for XXXX), which gets annoying.

Comment: Not if you remotely give a shit about performance and memory consumption. I would presume and encounter this where you have common data needing different prefixes in different contexts. No matter how you dice it, storing X extra characters increases your required memory by O(N)*prefix size.  Mine doesn't. And that's to say nothing about how much that prevents you from doing anything intelligent with memory alignment.
You also assume they will always be declared in code. Handle the more general problem and this is a worthwhile question for more than just OP's likely simplified sample he gave

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
string input;
const int len = 2;
string herp[len] = {"Merp", "Derp"}
cin >> input;

for( int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){
   if(input == herp [i])
      cout << "poopie" << endl;
```

Comment: As soon as he changes the length this breaks. If you are going to use '2' at least don't hardcode it as a magic number twice. It would also be nice if you could be consistent in your spacing.

Comment: I think the initial question is about a school exercise, and in the first times that you develop, you start with control flow. Yes, sure, '2' is hardcoded but I wanted to introduce an example of using the control flow statements.

Comment: All you have to do is say: `const int len(2)` and then use `len` and at least you haven't taught him to litter has code with magic numbers.  Easiest way to not pickup a bad habit is to never do it to start with.

Comment: As to what it's about it doesn't matter what you think it's about. SO is about being a globally useful resource.  As in useful for someone else who comes by with a similar or related looking for guidance. This isn't a homework help service.  By improving the code and stripping it down the basic problem we do this.. That's why the title was edited and those statements were removed. The problem is the problem regardless of why he has the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To highlight why jroc's (or Zac's) answer is so powerful, here's how you can use reuse to handle the append, or potentially suffix...  Note this is significantly more efficient `O(1)` than creating new strings each time by concatenation which render your entire solution down at `O(N)` and completely suck.

```
//this function can either be jroc's first or second variant implementation
bool jroc_find(const std::string& input, std::vector<string> array) { .... };

...
int main(...) {
    ...
    string input, search;
    cin >> input;
    string prefix("connect _");
    if (input.substr(0,prefix.length) != prefix )
        return -1; //not found
    else
        search = input.subst(prefix.length, input.length - prefix.length);
    return jroc_find(search, herp);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a couple approaches,

First, with a custom function,

```
template<typename ValueType, typename ForwardIterator>
bool is_in(ValueType value, ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end) {
    while (begin != end) {
        if (value == *(begin ++)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

template<typename ValueType, typename ForwardIterator>
bool is_in(ValueType value, ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end) {
    if (begin == end) return false;
    return value == *(begin ++) || is_in(value, begin, end);
}
```

They do basically the same thing, one that does it recursively, another iteratively.

Adding to jrok's answer, this also does the trick, but without lambda.

```
std::any_of(predicates.begin(), predicates.end(), std::bind(std::equal_to<std::string>(), "dance", std::placeholders::_1));
```

By using `std::bind` we can avoid using an additional lambda.

The last assumes that you have just a few constant predicates,

```
template<typename Comparable>
bool is_any(Comparable value) {
    return false;
}

template<typename ValueType, typename Comparable, typename... Comparables>
bool is_any(ValueType value, Comparable predicate, Comparables... predicates) {
    return value == predicate || is_any(value, predicates...);
}
```

You can just use it like this,

```
is_any("dance", "apple", "banana", "cat"); // false
```